# Import own enum converter

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a class which contains enum property.

```
public class Car{
    private UserAction action;
    //getters setters
}
```

And I want to save/read it from/to Mongo db. I am using Spring framework.

SpringConfig.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="dbName" />

    <bean id="mappingContext"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />

    <bean id="defaultMongoTypeMapper"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
        <constructor-arg name="typeKey"><null/></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mappingMongoConverter"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext" />
        <property name="typeMapper" ref="defaultMongoTypeMapper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingMongoConverter" />
    </bean>

<!--CODE BELOW CASES PROBLEMS-->

    <mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter">
        <mongo:custom-converters>
            <mongo:converter>
                <bean class="myapp.mongo.converters.UserActionReadConverter"/>
            </mongo:converter>
            <mongo:converter>
                <bean class="myapp.mongo.converters.UserActionWriteConverter"/>
            </mongo:converter>
        </mongo:custom-converters>
    </mongo:mapping-converter>

</beans>
```

UserActionReadConverter.java

```
package myapp.mongo.converters;

import myapp.model.UserAction;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class UserActionReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, UserAction> {

    public UserAction convert(DBObject source) {
        String val = (String) source.get("value");
        return (val.equals("PROCESSED_BY_USER" ) ? UserAction.PROCESSED_BY_USER : UserAction.UNPROCESSED_BY_USER);
    }
}
```

UserActionWriteConverter.java

```
package myapp.mongo.converters;

import myapp.model.UserAction;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

public class UserActionWriteConverter implements Converter<UserAction, DBObject> {

    public DBObject convert(UserAction userAction) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
        dbo.put("value", userAction.toString());
        return dbo;
    }
}
```

operations initialisation

```
...
ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");
this.operations = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean(beamName);
...
```

I have no idea, how to map converters into config .xml properly. It returns me error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

The second question is. I want to convert simple enum, to do that I use a "supporting identificator" value. Can I transform enum without using it, that data in database will be stores as {car.userAction : "data value" } instead of {car.value.userAction : "data value" } .Thanks.

Comment: are u using any validation from your controllers?

Comment: I am not sure, what controllers do you mean. For sake I edited question and added operations initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Missing validator library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```